# DNN Version upgrade from 06.01.03(108)

Tags: security, web, xss, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have Critical Updates available on my DNN v06.01.03(108).

AS per [Security Center](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/platform/manage/security-center) I should get upgraded to 7.4.1.

My Question is - do I need to do upgrade directly to 7.4.1 or in steps?

For e.g. 6.1.3 -> 6.2.9 -> 7.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would upgrade directly from 6.1.3 to 7.3.4.

Always back up your database and the file system before an upgrade, it is recommended that you do the upgrade in a test environment first, but if you don't have access to a test environment you can always restore to 6.1.3 from your backups if necessary.

Chris

Comment: Thanks @Chris. So the suggested upgrade path by DNN is not recommended now? http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/suggested-upgrade-path

Comment: I'm of the opinion you just go to the latest

Comment: Thanks @Chris! Everything went smooth. This saved my time.